# How to prove $(1+\sqrt{2})^n$ is an irrational number for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers

Let $k,m \in \mathbb{N}$, $a = k + m\sqrt{2}$

*I have proved that $a = k + m\sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number.*

Now, I am asked to prove that to every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $(1+\sqrt{2})^n$ is an irrational number.
And I can use what I have proved before (about $a = k + m\sqrt{2}$ being irrational).

I was advised to prove it with mathematical induction.

***The base***

We check the arguement for n=1:
$(1+\sqrt{2})^1 = 1+\sqrt{2}$

We define $k,m=1$ , and 1 is a natural, so $k,m \in \mathbb{N}$

so $(1+\sqrt{2})^1 = 1+\sqrt{2} =  k + m\sqrt{2}$ , Which I already proved to be irrational.

***Inductive step***

We assume $(1+\sqrt{2})^n$ is an irrational number.
We need to prove $(1+\sqrt{2})^{n+1}$ is also irrational.

So,
$(1+\sqrt{2})^{n+1}$ = $(1+\sqrt{2})^n \cdot (1+\sqrt{2})^1$
Because of exponent rules.

We proved in the base step that $(1+\sqrt{2})^1$ is irrational, and we assumed in the inductive step that $(1+\sqrt{2})^n$ is an irrational.

---

***But how does it help me forward?***

I cannot state that multiplication of 2 irrationals is an irrational. It is simply not true. So it is kind of confusing what I should do next.

Comment: Use the binomial theorem (or induction) to show that ${(1+\sqrt2)}^n=a_n+b_n\sqrt2$ for some integers $a_n,b_n$.

Comment: Be aware the there's no consensus about wherever $0$ should be included in $\Bbb N$ or not, so it's always a good idea to specify or use other notations.

Comment: in this case $0$ is not included inside the $\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your inductive step, assume that $\exists k, m > 0 : (1+\sqrt{2})^n = k + m\sqrt2$.  Then:

$$(1+\sqrt{2})^{n+1}$$
$$= (k + m\sqrt2)(1 + \sqrt 2)$$
$$= k + k\sqrt 2 + m\sqrt2 + 2m$$
$$= (k + 2m) + (k + m)\sqrt2$$

Since $k + 2m$ and $k + m$ are both positive integers, this expression fits the form that you have already proven to be irrational.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very different approach that doesn't necessarily use induction.

- Show that $ ( 1 + \sqrt{2})^n + (1 - \sqrt{2})^n$ is an integer $A$.

  - If we absolutely wanted, we can show this via induction.
- Show that $ ( 1 + \sqrt{2})^n \times (1 - \sqrt{2})^n$ is the integer 1.
- Hence, $( 1 + \sqrt{2})^n , (1 - \sqrt{2})^n$ are the roots of $ x^2 - Ax + 1 = 0$
- By the rational root theorem, the only possible rational roots are $ \pm \frac{1}{1}$.
- Show that $( 1 + \sqrt{2})^n > 1$, hence it is not rational.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: [Don't use induction.] Note that $(1+\sqrt{2})^{n}$ satisfies $(1+\sqrt{2})^{n} = a+ m\sqrt{2}$, where $a$ satisfies
$$a = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z};\ 0 \le 2k \le n} {n \choose {2k}}2^k,$$
and where $m$ satisfies
$$m = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}; \ 1 \le 2k+1 \le n} {n \choose {2k+1}}2^k.$$

[Make sure you see why this is.] However,
${n \choose {2k+1}}$ is positive and integral for every such $k$. So then, what can you conclude about ${n \choose {2k+1}}2^k$ being positive and integral? And thus $m$ as above, isn't it always nonzero and integral?